# SQL inner join getting all data in column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

This is my first time using an inner join so i'm very confused.

I have two tables.

[image: First one it: (I've blanked out details)]

This is my first table called members

[image]

This is my other table called donations. The userID from the members is linked up with the userID on the donations table.

Right so what i'm trying to do is select all of the data from members and from the donations table and assiotate each Id with the donation amount. So what i'm trying to do is echo all of the names along side their donation amount if that makes sense.

This is my code at the moment

$connect - contains my config

```
  //Connection info.
  global $connect;


  //inner join
  $sql = "SELECT members.firstname, members.lastname 
  FROM members INNER JOIN   donations ON members.userID = donations.userID WHERE donations.amount !='' ORDER BY members.userID ASC ";

  $result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql);


  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $list .= $row["firstname"];
    echo $list;
}
```

I'm getting this error back: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean

UPDATE: Thanks for all your help, i'm running the SQL query and just getting the first and last name back.

```
  SELECT members.firstname, members.lastname FROM members INNER JOIN   donations ON members.userID = donations.userID WHERE donations.amount !='' ORDER BY members.userID ASC
```

I think i'm doing something wrong here !=''  the donation amount is a decimal am i targeting it right?

Comment: you have members.fisrname , you have error in column name , use members.firstname in your query as i see your databse table

Comment: Thanks for your response fixed spelling. Still getting error think the error is being caused by  sql

Comment: print your query and try directly in phpmyadmin and see if it works

Comment: Is amount a `varchar` attribute? That is odd, I'd expect a `decimal`. If it is a `decimal` (or any other numeric datatype), why do you compare it with an empty string?

Comment: I think you might have an error in your where clause within the join. what type of field is donation.amount? you Are referring to it as a string. try to do where donations.amount is not null

Comment: Please see updated code appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `members.id` by `members.userID` in your query.

```
SELECT members.firstname, members.lastname, donations.amount 
FROM members
INNER JOIN donations ON members.userID = donations.userID
WHERE donations.amount != ''
ORDER BY members.userID ASC
```

As for the SQL error, it's because $result is `false` when there's a problem with the query or no result has been found.

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean

To prevent the error, add a simple if case because your while.

```
if($result){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       $list .= $row["firstname"];
       echo $list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, please could you have a look at my updated code?

Comment: Im just getting the first and last name back. I think I am targeting the donation amount wrong ? Its a decimal

Comment: No, that's because you're doing `SELECT members.firstname, members.lastname `, therefore, you're only retrieving the firstname and lastname from the database. Do you want to select the amount as well?

Comment: Yeah thats what i'm trying to so, i get the first name last and the donation amount associated to that userID if that makes sense ?

Comment: Really apprecitate your help

Comment: There, I updated the query. I added `donations.amount` in the select. Now you should get the first name, last name and the amount of the user.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help its working now. I get how it works now :)

Comment: No problem! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in column name 'fisrname' => 'firstname'.
Check the query first in phpmyadmin or the other tool. 
Also read about mysqli_error and later about other means of accessing the DB (like PDO, Doctrine etc.).

Comment: thanks for your response fixed spelling but still get ting errors.